# Where does the $*REPO dynamic variable obtain its values, and how to change/alter them?

Tags: raku, rakudo

> This question is complementary to figuring out why [this error](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4674) (which started as a [`zef` error](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/430)) occurs.

Apparently, in certain circumstances the repository chain accessible from `$*REPO` may vary. Namely, in a [GitHub action such as this one, where raku is part of a Docker image](https://github.com/JJ/p6-pod-load/runs/4574003162?check_suite_focus=true), all of a sudden the repository chain becomes:

```
(inst#/github/home/.raku inst#/usr/share/perl6/site inst#/usr/share/perl6/vendor inst#/usr/share/perl6/core ap# nqp# perl5#)
```

The first directory does not actually exist; this should be `/home/raku/.raku` instead. So a couple of questions

1. Why does rakudo install that unexisting directory as part of the repository chain
2. Is there any workaround that allows to simply change that value to the right one?

I don't really understand what's the cause for this happening. Initializing the container involves a long command line like this one:

```
/usr/bin/docker create --name d043d929507d4885927ac95002160d52_jjmereloalpinerakugha202110_1e6e32 --label 6a6825 --workdir /__w/p6-pod-load/p6-pod-load --network github_network_da048828784a46c3b413990beeaed866  -e "HOME=/github/home" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work":"/__w" -v "/home/runner/runners/2.285.1/externals":"/__e":ro -v "/home/runner/work/_temp":"/__w/_temp" -v "/home/runner/work/_actions":"/__w/_actions" -v "/opt/hostedtoolcache":"/__t" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" --entrypoint "tail" jjmerelo/alpine-raku:gha-2021.10 "-f" "/dev/null"
```

Where, effectively there seems to be an environment variable set to that value. So it might be that the environment variable `HOME` is the one that determines that, instead of whatever happened in the installation. But I don't know if that's a feature, or a bug.

Comment: @JJ Does .@ugexe's answer fully address the second part of your question? If not, please comment on what's missing. Thanks.

Comment: @raiph I know you like SO questions to get an answer, but it does not really address the second part. The answer is here: https://github.com/JJ/alpine-raku/blob/master/github-actions.Dockerfile, and it's not a workaround, it's simply a way to make Rakudo look into a specific directory by using `RAKULIB. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JJ Thanks. FWIW you've misunderstood my intent. I had read the comments and couldn't tell if you'd forgotten to accept .@ugexe's answer, or if it failed to fully address some part of your Q, or if you'd just not gotten around to updating/accepting yours with an answer that fully addressed your Q, or if there just wasn't yet a good answer, or...? And if I can't tell, others may be in the same boat, which isn't good for raku, or searchers, or readers, or answerers, or askers. When I see a Q where the asker hasn't clarified which it is, I consider asking them to comment. FWIW I'm *still* unsure.

Comment: @raiph I knew it was one or the other, and I really appreciate you taking the time to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `RAKULIB` to wherever your libraries were initially installed, as is done [here](https://github.com/JJ/alpine-raku/blob/master/github-actions.Dockerfile):

```
# Environment
ENV PATH="${WORKDIR}/.raku/bin:${WORKDIR}/.raku/share/perl6/site/bin:${PATH}" \
    ENV="${WORKDIR}/.profile"\
    RAKULIB="inst#/home/raku/.raku"
```

This part is underdocumented, but the `inst#` prefix reflects the fact that it includes precomp units, and the directory is where it was initially installed. Thus, no matter where `HOME` is, Rakudo will always find the original installed modules.

---

## Original answer

I don't have an answer to the second part, but I can answer the first part: the first element in the repository chain is taken from `$HOME` every time rakudo is started up. If the value of `$HOME` when `zef` or any other module was installed was different from the current one (case in point), one workaround would be do something like

```sh
HOME=/home/raku zef --version
```

Maybe create a shell function or an alias that does so, if you don't want to carry around the variable that way. Long term solution, really no idea.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does rakudo install that unexisting directory as part of the repository chain

Because you set `$HOME` to that directory. Unsurprisingly the `home` repository references `$HOME`.

> Is there any workaround that allows to simply change that value to the right one?

This doesn't need to be worked around, rather your environment needs to be setup properly. It appears you change `$HOME` to a non-existent directory, try to get zef to install to this new directory implicitly (which even if it did exist it probably wouldn't have permissions without you having done so), and when that failed you installed to `/home/raku` explicitly and wonder why your raku environment with a `/github/home` home directory/repo doesn't look in `/home/raku` (and how could it?). My suggestion is to figure out your file permission issues when you setup the new `$HOME` directory.

Comment: Why did you edit out the last part of the answer?

Comment: The half sentence .@MustafaAydın mentions is about being careful not to give folk the impression it makes sense in general to just "set `RAKULIB`". JJ just made that the accepted answer for this Q. He made the change in response to a comment by me intended to move us all toward clarity about a good answer to his Q. He misinterpreted it, and I suspect he felt pressured into doing something other than comment. It currently feels unclear to me whether you would now both agree that his answer is a good one for the particular case he describes in his Q. Any clarifying comment would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t really agree that setting rakulib as suggested (to another users home directory) is a good idea. Nor is the description that inst# means anything about precompilation. To me the accepted answers seems like something that was misunderstood but happens to work.